# play-services-vision: How do I calibrate the Landmark Detection?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I've tried out the `play-services-vision` library for face and landmark detection to calibrate some overlays I need to fit to my face, and for now I'm straight up copying Google's source code with some modifications in the FaceGraphic class.

The `FaceDetector.Builder` code is as follows:
`FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
                .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                .setMode(FaceDetector.ACCURATE_MODE)
                .setTrackingEnabled(true)
                .setProminentFaceOnly(true)
                .build();`

However, for some reason I observe that, even when my face stands still, the FaceDetector might be inconsistent with its landmark detection. Sometimes some of the landmarks go away, and all of the time the landmark points aren't where they're supposed to be - the eye points aren't in the eyes, etc.

What am I doing wrong? Should I calibrate the FaceDetector with the CameraSource in some way, and if so, how do I do it, and does this behavior have something to do with the layout I use for my CameraSourcePreview and GraphicOverlay views?

P.S. More of the source code will be provided when asked.

Comment: By *landmarks go away*, do you mean that the trackers do not appear at all? How long do you usually wait in front of the cam for the recognition process? With the `setClassificationType`, `setLandMarkType`, and `setMode` all put together, it would normally take more time for it to properly detect the landmarks. Have you tried testing it on different devices? Can you provide screenshots (with where trackers should be, and where it actually appears when you test it (for your privacy, I think you should blur your face, or maybe use a doll?)).

Comment: Yeah, the trackers might disappear at random. And about the trackers, they appear to the right and top of the detection rectangle instead of near or on the eyes. However, as I recently discovered, it's because I didn't use the translateX() and translateY() functions for the x and y coordinates of each landmark.

Comment: Have you tried setting the options (`setMode`, `setLandmarkType`, etc.) to aim for performance, see if it works that way first?

Comment: It works that way. Also, setLandmarkType only has ALL_LANDMARKS and NO_LANDMARKS.

Comment: If it works performance wise, it might be caused by something else. Try changing the value of parameters little by little (aiming for performance to accuracy), see which one causes the issue.

Comment: There's a bit of a problem now - the landmark coordinates are offset by some distance in the Y axis. Does it have something to do with the CameraSourcePreview not being full screen?